# pd.drop working outside a function but not in it

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

Working on creating a data frame from correlating two separate ones.
Everything is working smoothly, on it's own and in Jupyter where I check it independently.

I just added line another condition to drop a line from my dataframe - if it's a duplicate of the "current_edge['street_name'].
This line works in Jupyter notebook when I test, but not when I put it into the function.

```
# current_edge is a dictionary of values, edge_az is a float
# edge is my dataframe

for row in edge.index:

    if abs(current_edge['edgeAzimuth_deg'] - edge_az) <= turn_angle:
        edge = edge.drop(row)

    # drop same street names
    if edge['street_name'][row] == current_edge['street_name']:
        edge = edge.drop(row)
```

I'd expect it to drop one line from my current dataframe, but instead I'm receiving a KeyError = 0 on the condition line of code - "if edge['street_name']...."

This is honestly beyond me :-)
Any ideas why it would work outside the function but not once it's called?

Comment: Without seeing your function, I can't address the issue of different performance, but try replacing the last if statement with `if edge.loc[row, 'street_name'] == ...` to solve the KeyError.

Comment: What you're doing is an antipattern in pandas, BTW, the usual way to do it is `for index, row in edge.iterrows():`, then you get `row` as a series and your if statement would simple be `if row['street_name'] == ...`

Comment: If you want to drop all duplicate street_names, maybe think of using ```df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'street_name')``` on the final df? Just an alternate way of thinking. I'd probably just filter the first condition out of the final df too instead of your approach.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example, with data? I feel this could be simplified and vectorized (thus work much faster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that on row = 0, this condition is true

```
if abs(current_edge['edgeAzimuth_deg'] - edge_az) <= turn_angle:
        edge = edge.drop(row)
```

so, the row of index# 0 was dropped. The 2nd `if` condition tried to access index# 0, so it gives KeyError

```
if edge['street_name'][row] == current_edge['street_name']:
        edge = edge.drop(row)
```

Insert `print(edge.index)` between these 2 `if` to see whether index# 0 still existing after 1st `if`

Comment: You are 100% correct. Combined the two conditions and works.